# Strange SQL Server connection issues in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, docker, .net-core

I am using SQL Server 2019 Express running in a Windows container on Windows 10 and calling into it from a simple .NET Core 3.1 Web API application.

I have code that looks like this:

```
string conn = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
            {
                DataSource = "tcp:172.50.22.31\\SQLEXPRESS,9232",
                UserID = "sa",
                Password = "notThePassword18384.1",
                InitialCatalog = "master",
                IntegratedSecurity = false
            }.ConnectionString;

using (var con = new SqlConnection(conn))
{
    con.Open();
}
```

The connection string looks like this:

```
Data Source=tcp:172.50.22.31\SQLEXPRESS,9232;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=notThePassword18384.1
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Login failed for user 'sa'.'

I am running this from within a unit test in .NET Core 3.1, run from Visual Studio Test Explorer.

Now, the strange thing is - I can use the exact same connection string and connect via PowerShell:

```
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connectionString
$sqlConnection.Open()
Write-Output $sqlConnection.Database
Write-Output $sqlConnection.State
$sqlConnection.Close();
```

And this works fine. So I have a situation where the same connection string works just fine in PowerShell but doesn't work in .NET Core 3.1. I have even tried manually connecting to the SQL Server Express container from SQL Server Management Studio and it also works fine. I have turned off all the firewalls on my computer. I have also tried all sorts of permutations of the connection string in C# and it won't work.  Also tried this on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016 with the same outcome on both.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might not be working? For me it is so strange that it doesn't work in C# but it works in PowerShell with the same connection string.

Update: Added SQL Connection String builder per AlwaysLearning

Update: Per Preben Hyubrechts, tried executing sp_readerrorlog:

`EXEC sp_readerrorlog`

Which produced:

> Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 7.
> Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: An error occurred while evaluating the password. [CLIENT: 172.50.22.31]

This appears to indicate that the client is connecting to the server, it is just having an error while evaluating the password.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Do you see the failed login attempts in SQL Server?

Comment: @GSerg Thanks, how can I check for failed login attempts in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your actual connection string in C# code? Mask out the username and password, of course. If you're using a regular string literal the backslash needs to be escaped, `"ServerName\\InstanceName"`, but if it's a verbatim string literal a single backslash is fine, `@"ServerName\InstanceName"`.

Comment: I agree with @AlwaysLearning, probably you are using the wrong connection string in c#.

Comment: *"I am running this from within a unit test"* - Which user account is running the test driver?

Comment: You can see the error log using `sp_readerrorlog`

Comment: The error you get from a connection string that can't find the instance will be different from the error you get if the password is incorrect. If the application sits for a few seconds on that line of code and then you get something like "a network related or instance specific error occured" then you are not even getting to the server. But if you're getting "Login failed for user 'sa'", then you are connecting to the instance and being rejected because the password is wrong. Double check your password. Maybe it has a backslash in it and you're not escaping it, or using a verbatim string.

Comment: You are making the connection from two different windows operating systems to the same server.  The windows machines need to be in the same group for connection to be successful since window to window communication is secure.

Comment: @jdweng The OP is using SQL authentication, as opposed to Windows authentication. If they did use Windows authentication, it's a quite bit more complex than belonging to the same workgroup.

Comment: SQL Authentication will not work when you are connecting to a remote server.

Comment: @jdweng SQL authentication [will](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authentication-in-sql-server#authentication-scenarios) most certainly work when connecting to a remote server.

Comment: I've never seen it work.  Do you have an example when server were not part of the same group?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I updated to include the C# aspect of the connection string (it is created using Microsoft's SqlConnectionStringBuilder class)

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts Thanks for the suggestion - I added the output from this above - any thoughts?

Comment: @Abr [This thread](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/55) seems to be a good match for your issue, since you mentioned you were using a container. Look through the whole thread, not just the first answer. Containers come up about 10 comments in.

Comment: Can you post a docker run command that you are using? If you create a new container with a really simple password does this repro?  This is a strange error message and I'd like to get a repro.

Comment: Just a wild guess and probably not the issue, but try leaving off `\sqlexpress`. In general, you either specify an instance name or a port; specifying both is redundant and a possible source of errors by assumption. With only an instance name, the browser service will be used to look up the port; with a port, the instance name is irrelevant as you can only be connected to the instance listening on that port.

Comment: With both the client it ignores the instance name and connects to the target port.

Comment: Ah, then `tcp:server\instance` would be extra confusing as it attempts to connect to 1433, right? Then there's really no reason to ever specify the instance name if you're using `tcp:` since all it can do is confuse (you might think you're connecting to an instance that you're not in fact connecting to).